# Traversing XML elements does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8

I am a newbie to javascript but here is what I am trying to do. Note that I looked around for an answer but nothing helped.

I am trying to traverse XML elements but it is not working in IE8. It is working just fine in Firefox though. And by not working I mean it doesn't go inside the loop even though there are elements.

This is the XML I am trying to traverse:

```
var $anXml = $('<node id="anID" inline="0" leaf="true">'
                  +'<sub_node1>Text \(more text\)</sub_node1>'
                  +'<sub_node2>Text \(more text\)</sub_node2>'
             +'</node>');
```

Here is the code I am using to traverse:

```
alert('children before loop: ' + $anXml.children.length);
$anXml.children().each(function() {
    alert('child traversed!');
    var $aChild = $(this);
    $anotherXml.data(this.nodeName.toLowerCase(), $aChild.html());
});
alert('children after loop: ' + $anXml.children.length);
```

Here is the output of alerts:

```
children before loop: 2
children after loop: 2
```

The 'child traversed!' is never displayed.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if `$anXml.children.length` is working, it's not a jQuery object as [.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) is a property of a native element, not jQuery, so you have to wrap it  :

```
$($anXml).children().each(function() {
    alert('child traversed!');
    var $aChild = $(this);
    $anotherXml.data(this.nodeName.toLowerCase(), $aChild.html());
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. I noticed that it works for other docs. I wonder if it to has to do with the way my anXml is structured.

Comment: Is the XML parsed with $.parseXML before you're trying to use it, and is it valid XML

Comment: No. I'm just accessing some attributes using the .attr. The XML is what I have above, which I believe is a valid XML, and it works in FireFox. Would it work in FireFox if it was invalid?

Comment: Alert($anotherXml.data('sub_node1')) after the loop displays "undefined". Not sure if this helps understanding what is happening.

Comment: I had to use $.parseXML() to be able to use JQuery functions such as .find(). However, the loop still does not work. Note that I had to create a string XML, pass it to the $.parseXML(), then wrap it. I.e. I followed jQuery.parseXML() documentation.